# Setting up Oculus Rift in Unity with OpenVR + SteamVR

Tags: unity-game-engine, steam, oculus, openvr

Hi I'm trying to set up my Oculus Rift in Unity to develop with OpenVR and Steam. I'm using Unity version 2017.4 and have added the SteamVR package from the asset store to my project. I'm guessing I need to download the github OpenVR folder and add to my project, but is that all? and will the Rift be recognised then? I'm not sure if I need the Oculus integration tool from the asset store as well or will it interfere? Any step by step assistance would be amazing, thank you in advance (also, I know developing with Oculus and not Steam might be easier but need to use Steam for this project)

Comment: Dear Matthew, welcome to StackOverflow. You question is more like asking for a tutorial to start developing Oculus Rift. StackOverflow is thought for more specific questions where you show what you have already tried. I suggest you find a good tutorial and come back when you find obstacles.

Comment: Matthew, since its been a few months, I'm wondering if you have sorted this out and have any advice on this. I am also trying to get OpenVR/SteamVR dev env working for Oculus Rift.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working with Oculus Rift so...

First you need to download Oculus Rift Software. It will help you setup your Rift. You can download it [HERE](https://www.oculus.com/setup/)

Second, you probably need Oculus Rift SDK for Unity. It's working perfectly well for me. I just click `Play` and app is starting in Oculus Rift. You can download it [HERE](https://developer.oculus.com/downloads/package/oculus-utilities-for-unity-5/). And use `Import Asset` to add in to your Unity Project. I highly recommend also [Oculus Rift Avatar SDK](https://developer.oculus.com/downloads/package/oculus-avatar-sdk/) (for hands and nice support for Touch Controllers) and [Oculus Rift Sample Framework](https://developer.oculus.com/downloads/package/oculus-sample-framework-for-unity-5-project/) for prefabs (like grabbers for grabbing things obviously).

Also if you will have any problems, remember to update your USB Drivers (especially for USB 3.0).